# Como puxar uma função específica do JavaScript pro HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho um site e estou com dificuldades, os códigos de JavaScript estão todos misturados com html porque quando eu coloco em apenas 1 arquivo ele não roda no html, tem que abrir uma tag  abaixo de cada item que tem função.
Queria saber: Como eu faço para rodar todas as funções do site sem precisar abrir uma tag  abaixo de cada item que possui uma função no js? Detalhe, preciso de 1 arquivo para cada página ou apenas 1 arquivo com todas as funções?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o exemplo de uma página com o html com o js ?

Comment: Boa tarde. Precisa de um [mcve] em sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Poste seu código nas próximas perguntas

Existe a tag `<script>`
Você pode utilizar ela e "puxar" as funções de um arquivo utilizando o `src`

Vamos supor que seu arquivo se chame `index.js`

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

O `src` é de onde está vindo o arquivo, desta forma você pode ter várias funções em um arquivo, ou vários arquivos pra cada página.

Espero que tenha entendido

Comment: Obrigado, entendi sim !!

Comment: Depois de ler essa resposta que entendi a pergunta.